# Reload PHP file in command line PHP-CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have one PHP file like below which I run in command prompt using below command

```
php myfile.php
```

and its working fine. I want keep running it 24/7 and its running but sometime if there any error come, its stop working so I want reload file in same command prompt. I am using it in centos, and I want see result in command prompt so Cron Job is not useful for me. I want put code which can stop file running and start it again.

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);
require_once ('src/whats.class.php');
$starttime = time();
global $w;
connectwa();


function onGetMessage($object)
{
    global $w;
    $message = $object->getMessage();
    $contact = explode("@", $object->getFrom()) [0];
    $type = "You have sent *Simple Text* Message.";
    sendMessage($contact, $type, $message);
}


function connectwa() {
    global $w;
    $wait = mt_rand(10, 15);
    global $waittime;
    $waittime = $wait*60;
    echo $waittime;
    $log = false;
    $debug = false;
    $nickname = 'Number1';
    $username = 'Your Number will be Here';
    $password = 'Your Password will be here';
    $w = new Whats($username, $nickname, $debug, $log);
    $w->eventManager()->bind('onGetMessage', 'onGetMessage');

    try {
        $w->connect();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Connection error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit(0);
    }

    try {
        $w->loginWithPassword($password);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Login error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit(0);
    }
    echo "connected \n";
}

while (1) {
    try {
        $w->pollMessage();

        if (time() - $starttime > $waittime) {
            echo "Disconnecting\n";
            $starttime = time();
            $w->disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
    }

    if (!$w->isConnected()) {
        echo "disconnected\n";
        system('clear');
        connectwa();
    }
}
?>
```

I can clear output result from command using below code in php

```
system('clear');
```

let me know there similar code which can reload my current file.
Thanks

Comment: Does your catch, catch the errors? And what do you do in your catch block?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using catch(Exception $e), when any error arrive there, I want reload my file. Thanks

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish by "stop current file and want run it again" when there is an error?  Why can't you allow the script to just keep running?

Comment: @PatrickQ  its socket connection based file and so sometime its getting stopped with some errors, its start working when we run it again so I am looking command for automatically run file again if there any errors come and file get stopped.

Comment: Personally, I would try to figure out the cause of the errors, and resolve that.  Simply running your file again seems like an awfully indirect solution.  The errors may be an indication that you're trying to do something in a way that you shouldn't be.

Comment: @PatrickQ I am basically looking command code which can reload my file. It will solve my all issue. something like system('clear'); Thanks

Comment: why not just close and repoen the connection in the catch. i.e. clean up and start processing again. Then the script does not need restarting

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thats also Good, Can You please give any example for that? Thanks

Comment: Well if you show me yours I will show you mine so to speak! Lets see what you currently do in the catch block

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have put just exit(0); in catch block. Let me know its enough or I need put my full file here. Thanks a lot

Comment: Well that why your script terminates! Ok so to be helpful I need to see more code. I cannot help you do the cleanup code for a process I have no idea about

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added my original full file. Let me know if now you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this on a number of occasions to keep a PHP script running, and ensure it keeps re-running when it exits.  More importantly is be able to slow things down if they start to run-away with uncaught errors however.   In PHP 7+, catching the most base Exception (a `\Throwable` ensures that all exceptions that could be thrown are caught).

```
#!/bin/bash

nice php -q -f ./myfile.php -- $@
exec $0 $@
```

Whatever parameters are passed to the shell script, are passed into the PHP script, and when the PHP file exits, then the shell script re-runs itself (not recursively, it replaces itself) to run again. Within the PHP script you can loop as much as you like, but since restarting it is so simple and fast, I might do 50-100 loops before deliberately exiting to clean anything up.

I further extend that simple 3-line script with some options that I can communicate out with `exit $n;`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# a shell script that keeps looping until an exit code is given
# if it does an exit(0), restart after a second - or if it's a declared error
# if we've restarted in a planned fashion, we don't bother with any pause
# and for one particular code, exit the script entirely.
# The numbers 97, 98, 99 must match what is returned from the PHP script

nice php -q -f ./cli-beanstalk-worker.php -- $@
ERR=$?

## Possibilities
# 97    - planned pause/restart `exit 97;`
# 98    - planned restart (immediate, no sleep)
# 99    - planned stop, exit.
# 0     - unplanned restart (as returned by "exit;" or exceptions)
#        - Anything else is also unplanned paused/restart

if [ $ERR -eq 97 ]
then
   # a planned pause, then restart
   echo "97: PLANNED_PAUSE - wait 2";
   sleep 2;
   exec $0 $@;
fi
# ... other choices to potentially pause, or exit the shell script

# unplanned exit, pause, and restart
echo "unplanned restart: err:" $ERR;
echo "sleeping for 5 secs"
sleep 5

# rerun this shell script, replacing itself
exec $0 $@
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Its Bash Script? I am new in Linux. I need include this code in MY PHP file? Thanks

Comment: This code would be extra and you run it. It runs the php file, and restarts it whenever it fails.  I've blogged about running such systems, https://phpscaling.com/2009/06/23/doing-the-work-elsewhere-sidebar-running-the-worker though that is for processing queues, and not dealing with web-sockets, as you may be dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Use try/catch block inside your while loop. This way, the script will not break on error or exception. you can use catch block to log your errors as well. And the script will continue running for ever.

**NOTE**

If this is a shared hosting/server then applying the time limit may not have any impact. And script will break after a set amount of time. But I hope, you are doing this on your personal/dedicated server.

Comment: "Use try/catch block inside your while loop"  OP is already doing that

Comment: Hi! I am using it in private VPS and I have already used catch(Exception $e). I want reload file when error come. Thanks

Comment: if your scripts breaks even with try/catch then possibly error is on some other place. try to place the IF block inside the TRY block.  or see at what line error occurs, try to encircle that  script into try/catch block.

Comment: @MalikAhmedKhanAwan I am basically looking command code which can reload my file. It will solve my issue. something like system('clear'); Thanks